# Find value of string in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I've been working on this simple script for a few hours now and have hit a wall. I have an Array comprised of JSON values. When a user searches for a string and clicks the button, the script checks the string against the values stored in the Array.

The section I'm stuck on is the conditional, which always returns no match - even if I enter a string which I know is in the JSON file.

Code below. Any guidance/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Mark.

```
    $('#validate-info').on('click', function(){

      // Get data, initiate callback
      $.getJSON('memberships.json', validateMembership);
      // Execute callback function
      function validateMembership(data) {

        // Capture entered value
        var userVal = document.getElementById('form-data').value;
        console.log(userVal);

        var infoTxt = '';

        // Push all items into an Array
        var infoArray = [];

        $.each(data, function(member, memberInfo) {
          infoTxt += '<p><strong>Name:</strong> ' + memberInfo.name + '<br />';
          infoTxt += '<strong>Membership No.:</strong> ' + memberInfo.number + '<br />';
          infoTxt += '<strong>Expiry Date:</strong> ' + memberInfo.expiry + '</p>';
          infoArray.push({
              name: memberInfo.name, 
              number:  memberInfo.number,
              expiry: memberInfo.expiry
          });
        });

        if ($.inArray(userVal, infoArray) > -1 ) { 
          // the value is in the array
          $('#response').html('<p style="color: green;">In the array</p>');
        } else {
          $('#response').html('<p style="color: red;">Sorry, no matches.</p>');
        }

      }

    });
```

Comment: you are trying to find  a matching string from an array of objects. Are you trying to match `userVal` in `name` property?

Comment: Just check inside the `each` loop and set a flag variable to true if match exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing the input string against the objects, and they'll never match. You need to compare just with the name. You can use the `Array.prototype.some` function to test if any of them match.

```
if (infoArray.some(function(obj) {
    return obj.name == userVal;
})) {
    $('#response').html('<p style="color: green;">In the array</p>');
} else {
    $('#response').html('<p style="color: red;">Sorry, no matches.</p>');
}
```

You could also do it during the loop that pushes into `infoArray`.

```
var match = false;
$.each(data, function(member, memberInfo) {
  infoTxt += '<p><strong>Name:</strong> ' + memberInfo.name + '<br />';
  infoTxt += '<strong>Membership No.:</strong> ' + memberInfo.number + '<br />';
  infoTxt += '<strong>Expiry Date:</strong> ' + memberInfo.expiry + '</p>';
  infoArray.push({
      name: memberInfo.name, 
      number:  memberInfo.number,
      expiry: memberInfo.expiry
  });
  if (memberInfo.name == userVal) {
    match = true;
  }
});

if (match) {
    $('#response').html('<p style="color: green;">In the array</p>');
} else {
    $('#response').html('<p style="color: red;">Sorry, no matches.</p>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar. Great insight and it helped me a lot. Is there anyway of extending this beyond a simple truthy/falsey condition? For example, if I did get a match, how would I go about returning the matched value?

For example if the memberInfo.name value returns a match with the userVal, then I want to be able to output that matched object value.

Comment: When you get a match, put it in a variable, and then use that variable after the loop is done.

Comment: `if (memberInfo.name == userVal) { match = memberInfo; }`